# how to write a dictionary with one key multiple values to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a dictionary of the following form

```
>>> {'1' : [V3210 , 234567 ,1235675 , 23], '2' : [v3214 , 5678 ,65879 ,89} , ...}
```

how to write this dictionary to a csv file??

thanks

Comment: how the  csv file looks like?

Comment: Are those 1, 2, 3 always numeric, sequential and without gaps.  Can they be used as line numbers

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote what you wanted the CSV file to look like.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Answer (score 2):

Use the builtin [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module. This is assuming you want it in a `key,value1,value2,...` format.

```
import csv

with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)

    for key, value in d.items():
        c.writerow([key] + value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numeric keys are line numbers, try something like this:

```
theDict = {'1' : [V3210 , 234567 ,1235675 , 23], '2' : [v3214 , 5678 ,65879 ,89] }
largestkey=max(map(int,theDict.keys()))
with file("out.csv") as f:
    for linenum in range(largestkey+1):
        f.write(",".join(theDict[str(linenum)])
        f.write("\n")
```

You'll want to look at Python's string API, list handling, and file handling to get more familiar with Python...

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) would make doing this super simple:

```
import csv

d = {'1' : ['V3210', 234567, 1235675, 23], '2' : ['v3214', 5678, 65879 ,89], }

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows([row[0]] + row[1] for row in d.iteritems())
```

Note the `iteritems()` dictionary method is gone in Python 3, so you'd need to use `d.items()` instead.